# Find the element with most occurrences in a list in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I find the element with most occurrences in a list?

If there are more with the same number, any can be returned.

For example, for  the list `'(1 3 3 4 2 2)`, the function can return either `2` or `3`.

I'm thinking I can count the number of occurrences of each element and then select the maximum, but that seems kinda inefficient. Is there any better way, or even better, a built-in function?

Comment: Are elements if the list numbers?

Comment: @soegaard I presume it doesn't really matter as long as they're all `eqv?`-comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A R6RS Scheme `O(n)` version using [SRFI-69 hash tables](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html)

```scm
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (srfi :69))

(define (max-occurence lst)
  (define hash (make-hash-table))
  (define zero (lambda () 0))
  (let loop ((lst lst) (mfreq 0) (mcur #f))
    (if (null? lst)
        mcur
        (let* ((element (car lst)) (freq (+ 1 (hash-table-ref hash element zero))))
          (hash-table-set! hash element freq)
          (if (> freq mfreq)
              (loop (cdr lst) freq element)
              (loop (cdr lst) mfreq mcur))))))
```

A `#!racket` version of the same is very similar except the idiomatic version would choose immutable hash tables.

```scm
#!racket

(define (max-occurence lst)
  (let loop ((hash (make-immutable-hash)) (lst lst) (mfreq 0) (mcur #f))
    (if (null? lst)
        mcur
        (let* ((element (car lst)) (freq (add1 (hash-ref hash element 0))))
          (if (> freq mfreq)
              (loop (hash-set hash element freq)
                    (cdr lst)
                    freq
                    element)
              (loop (hash-set hash element freq)
                    (cdr lst)
                    mfreq
                    mcur))))))
```

In the event you get performance issues with lists I guess you'll see great improvement with either of these. Changing to mutable hash tables in `#!racket` would double the speed but I doubt you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on Racket hash tables.

```
#lang racket
(define (most-frequent-element xs)
  (define ht (make-hash))
  (for ([x xs]) (hash-update! ht x add1 0))
  (for/fold ([max-x #f] [max-count 0]) ([(x c) ht])
    (if (> c max-count)
        (values x c)
        (values max-x max-count))))
```

Example:

```
> (most-frequent-element '(a b c c d a a b c a))
'a
4
```

Here is a solution with `argmax`. Unfortunately it requires 
a conversion from hash table to list.

```
#lang racket

(define (most-frequent-element xs)
  (define ht (make-hash))
  (for ([x xs]) (hash-update! ht x add1 0))
  (argmax (λ (x) (hash-ref ht x 0)) 
          (hash->list ht)))
```

Example:

```
> (most-frequent-element '(a b c c d a a b c a))
'(a . 4)
```

Comment: I like this. Although conceptually the `for/fold` could be simplified to `(argmax cdr (hash->list ht))`, that would be at least somewhat slower.

Comment: I added a version using `argmax`.

Comment: I improved the first version a little. [(x c) ht] will iterate over both the key x and its value c (the count).

Answer (score 0):

You can be slightly more efficient if you sort the list before counting. Then all the elements with a particular value would be together in the list. Then, when you get done counting the 2's in your example list, you wouldn't have to keep the number of 1's anymore, since your function would already know that 1 isn't the element with the most occurrences.